# How to get id from request/response in JSF?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have such id of dialog form `form:processFilterPanel_fpanel_tv:dialogFormIO:j_idt195:ItemWidget_input`

And I want to work with one element of form at backend side. The problem that this part of id `j_idt195` is always changing by jsf (when it starts a new session) and I don't know how to get it. Have any ideas?

Comment: sure, find out what naming container does not have a fixed id assigned by you and assign it one.

Comment: Maybe try to set a id on your dialog, so it will be the same on every session.

Comment: @stakahop , Unfortunately I already use id `ItemWidget`. I have main form `form:processFilterPanel_fpanel_tv` and component is located on form (`dialogFormIO`), which appears when the button is pressed. And if I don't indicate the whole path, I will have ComponentNotFoundException

Comment: Omnifaces can help finding them http://showcase.omnifaces.org/viewhandlers/NoAutoGeneratedIdViewHandler

Answer (score 0):

Just use id="yourFavId" on the component and reference it.

JSF gives those weird looking ids to the html components that didn't have a defined one.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but what is 'the' component? This and your second sentence is al described in high detail in the 'duplicate'... Please mark this question as such..

Comment: In his first sentence he tells us about it: The form, which has the id that he can't manage. Also, sadly, I can't cast closing votes because of duplication or any other reason.

Comment: Unfortunately I already use it `ItemWidget`. I have main form `form:processFilterPanel_fpanel_tv` and component is located on form (`dialogFormIO`), which appears when the button is pressed. And if I don't indicate the whole path, I will have ComponentNotFoundException

Comment: Have you tried widgetVar from primefaces?

Comment: @Jorge.V, @Kukeltje, thank you, I solve my problem. I had 1 unnamed container (it was `fluidGrid`), I just gave it an id and the problem is solved